# I recently installed ubuntu into my system and it just keeps on loading on selecting windows 10. What should I do?

Tags: dual-boot

On selecting windows 10, it just displays the windows booting picture and never opens Windows. Ultimately, I have to switch off my PC and then restart it. How should I recover my windows?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. May need chkdsk, but most often problem is hibernation which even if you turned it off before Windows on major updates turns back on. If UEFI you can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions But if BIOS install, you will have to temporarily reinstall a Windows boot loader to MBR using your Windows repair/recovery flash drive.

Comment: It depends, some BIOS (UEFI) allow you to select which OS to boot by hitting F8 or some other key. Other times you will need to repair windows. Are you using legacy boot or UEFI ? Sometimes you can fix this by running boot-repair from Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)